# Can we expose a public url for images from OpenShift?

Tags: flask, openshift

I've created a REST webservice in [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com) using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework.

Everything is working fine. Now, I want to expose a public url to fetch images. Is there a way to do that using flask or we can directly fetch the images. i.e www.something.com/image.jpg this url should directly provide the image.

For now I'm trying out flask- send_file method to provide the image. Is it the way to provide the image?

Comment: If these are images on the disk you may want to look in to having the web server send these.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some sort of authentication or you need to check something in the request before sending the image, you're sending images dynamically.
`send_file` is the solution here cause it uses the underlying webserver implementation if available.

From [Flask docs on `send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file):

> [...] This will use the most efficient method available and configured. By default it will try to use the WSGI server’s file_wrapper support. Alternatively you can set the application’s use_x_sendfile attribute to True to directly emit an X-Sendfile header. This however requires support of the underlying webserver for X-Sendfile. [...]

Comment: I used the send_file() method to send images.

But my concern is that the url should be public url in OpenShift which allows to fetch the images. It should not pass through the webservice.

Webservice is used to upload images but for fetching images we should provide a public url for images. Therefore, www.domainname.com/images/image_name.png 
should provide the required image.
Is it possible through OpenShift or could we use other image hosting sites?
Right now my friend is using [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/) for fetching the images.